# Ruby iterate over multiple values for single key

Tags: ruby, file, hash, key

Okay so I have a hash with a keys where some contain multiple values per key. I am trying to create new files with key being the filename and values being written to the text while (one value per line). Here is what I got.

```
    @agencyList.each do |domain, email|
        File.open(domain.to_s, "w") { |file| file.write(email) }
    end
```

The issue is only the first element of value set is being outputted to the file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood correctly `@agencyList` is an array of `Hash`es. For example:

```
@agencyList = [
  {domain: 'domain1', email: 'email11'},
  {domain: 'domain1', email: 'email12'},
  {domain: 'domain2', email: 'email21'},
]
```

So in this case `File.open(domain.to_s, "w")` has incorrect file mode. `w` will recreate a new file so this file will contain always only one value - the last one.

Try to open files with `a` mode and write lines via `puts` to ensure that values will be on separate lines:

```
@agencyList.each do |hash|
  File.open(hash[:domain].to_s, "a") { |file| file.puts(hash[:email]) }
end
```

**OR**

But if you are saying

> I have a hash with a keys where some contain multiple values per key

A `Hash` cannot contain values with the same key. So your `@agencyList` is a `Hash` and should have values as an array:

```
@agencyList = {
  'key1' => ['val11', 'val12'],
  'key2' => ['val21'],
]
```

If so your code should be something like this:

```
@agencyList.each do |domain, emails|
  File.open(domain.to_s, "w") do |file|
    emails.each do |email|
      file.puts(email)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to iterate over the emails set

```
domains.each { |domain, emails|
   File.open(domain, 'w'){ |f|
      emails.each { |email|
         f.puts(email)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: for multi-lines blocks use `do..end`...instead of `{..}`.

Comment: Thanks Arup, for the purpose of clarity? or is there a technical difference also, cheers.

Comment: ste, it is just convention to do as Arup suggests.  Most Rubiests believe it is easier to read multi-line constructs when `do/end` is used instead of braces.  You may disagree, but there is something to say for following convention, particularly when you are learning a new programming language.  Incidentally, Arup would not have been notified that you replied to his comment (and therefore may never see it). If you want him to be notified, preface his name with a `@` (i.e., @Arup).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for notifying me and well explained. OP - search the [link](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) with this sentence - *Prefer `{...}` over `do...end` for single-line blocks*.